# What does THIS code do when deleting data from the database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Can someone explain what the first piece of code does? I understand that the second piece of code is deleting everything in the RoutineTable where the DayOfWeek is the selectedDay. If some could walk me through it that would be amazing!! Thank you in advance!

The first piece of code....

```
private void deleteRoutine() {
myDb.deleteRoutineForCurrentDay(currentDay);
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

}

The second piece of code....

```
public void deleteRoutineForCurrentDay(String selectedDay)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + RoutineTable + " WHERE DayOfWeek ='" + selectedDay + "'");
}
```

P.S. If anyone could explain the difference between using a db.execSQL, db.rawQuery and a db.insert?

Comment: The documentation states the differences between those calls fairly clearly: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Please, stop adding the `android-studio` tag to your posts. The IDE is totally **irrelevant**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have line by line

```
myDb.deleteRoutineForCurrentDay(currentDay);
```

Execute your method that delete the data from your table in your variable

Then

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

You get the instance in order to use intents.

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Here you made a mnistake, yes it needs two ints but they are two animations, with the int you can make a reference to the animations that will be executed instead the default animation.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

You unset the animation transition when the another activity starts

with: `finish();`

You are calling the method On destroy that is used for:

- Dismiss any dialogs the activity was managing.
- Close any cursors the activity was managing.
- Close any open search dialog

and with `startActivity(intent);`

You will have an error because you don have a reference to an activity or even a class.

**For your another question**

> P.S. If anyone could explain the difference between using a db.execSQL, db.rawQuery and a db.insert?

Internally I don't know the diference but with

```
db.execSQL();
```

You just execute a SQL instruction and it doesn't throw a response.

```
db.rawQuery();
```

You have a cursor as a result which can be used for any purpose.

and with `db.insert();`

You have a way to build your query without SQL, you just put your data and thats all.

Here you have more info.

[SQLiteDatabase Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

I hope my explanations helps you.

Good Luck :3

Comment: Thank you very much cookieCat. This is most helpful!

Comment: Mark the answer please :3

Comment: Sorry new here. I ticked the green tick icon